# Communicating with Pole Display

Tags: c#, php, ports

I am using a Posiflex Customer Pole display, [PD-3000](http://www.posiflexusa.com/pole_display30.php)

It's connected via a USB port (Hence I can't just right "COM" in C#). I would like to put a simple application that shows welcome message or some text to display on it.

How to proceed?

Can it be done in PHP as well? Or would I have to stick with C#? Also, it provides only OPOS software - which frankly makes no sense.